# Help with dual booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-7

I have recently attempted to install Ubuntu 14.04 onto a partition on my hard drive, which is about 60GB in size. I was able to install it onto the partition.

After the installation is finished, I got the box that says restart the computer, and I did.

After rebooting, I don't get a choice to boot between Windows and Ubuntu, it just straight up boots into Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), it's a simple tool to repair frequent boot issues.

1- [DOWNLOAD BOOT-REPAIR-DISK](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/).

2- Then burn it on a live-USB key via [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).

3- Insert the Boot-Repair-Disk and reboot the PC.

4- Choose your language.

5- Connect internet if possible.

6- Click "Recommended repair".

7- Reboot the pc.

Comment: Do I have to use a keep the Ubuntu installer plugged into the computer for this to work?

Comment: @cooljj21, I didn't understand your question !

Comment: Can I put that Boot Repair onto the same USB that I used for the Ubuntu installations? Or will I have to wipe the USB to use the Boot Repair?

Comment: It's better to wipe the USB.